# How to create objects based on XML file at build time

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I am making a puzzle game where I prepared all the logical cases in Excel (this allows me a lot of flexibility in regard of difficulty settings, fine tuning probabilities...).

I did these steps:

1. Data from excel I converted into XML format
2. I can currently successfully read the data from XML and make the instances in game based on class "ItemDefinition"
3. During the playtime can the game select the best fitting instance to the situation and use it in game (I am storing all instances in list "itemList", and their weighted probability in dictionary "weightsDict")

Issues

- For testing purposes with XML of only 50 cases, all works well
- In real life I will have around 35,000 cases in XML  = XML file size is around 2 MB, but during one game I only use couple cases from XML file
- My implementation is using instances, which are created when the game starts, i.e. "Awake () {}"
- But then it leads to the situation that the user have to wait 15 minutes to start the game just because the game is creating instances based on XML file... what is really not smart as all 35,000 cases in the background are always the same...

Question

- Shall I implement it completely different way?? For example, not to do a class/instances when game starts but instead read a random XML during playtime... is it possible to implement it - how? Especially with weighted probability?
- Or, if my approach is in general correct -> if how to create instances from XML at build time i.e. when exporting game to device??
  So that 35,000 instances do not need to be created each time when the game starts...

---

### Example of coding... see below

```xml
<xml>
<item size="3" weight="1" digit1="2" .../>
<item size="4" weight="2" digit1="3" .../>
...
</xml>
```

```cs
    public class ItemDefinition
    {   
        public int size;
        public float weight;
        public float digit1;
        ...
    }
```

```cs
    public class ReadFlowXML : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Header("Set in Inspector")]
        TextAsset XMLtoRead;
        [Header("Set Dynamically")]
        PT_XMLReader xmlr;
        List<ItemDefinition> itemList= new List<ItemDefinition>();
        Dictionary<int, float> weightsDict = new Dictionary<int,float>();
         void Awake()
         {
            ReadXML(XMLtoRead.ToString());
         }
         public void ReadXML(string flowsXML)
         {
            PT_XMLReader xmlr = new PT_XMLReader();
            xmlr.Parse(flowsXML); 
            PT_XMLHashList xFlow = xmlr.xml["xml"][0]["item"];        
            for (int i = 0; i < xFlow.Count; i++)
            {
               ItemDefinition tempItem;
               tempItem.size = int.Parse(xFlow[i].att("size"));
               tempItem.weight = float.Parse(xFlow[i].att("weight"));
               tempItem.digit1 = float.Parse(xFlow[i].att("digit1"));
               ...
               itemList.Add(tempItem);
               weightsDict.Add(weightsDict.Count, priorPosition + tempItem.weight);
            }
         }
    }
```

PS: I am using external PT_XMLReader and PT_XMLHashList to read the text asset

Comment: So what exactly is your question? "How to do something before a build?" -> [Build Preprocessor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport.OnPreprocessBuild.html) .. or "How to deserialize XML files" -> [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer) ... etc .. please try to be more specific and focus on one single specific issue/question. In general 35.000 objects should at best be data classes and not actually GameObjects or assets otherwise it will have a huge impact

Comment: Now I do this : 1) data is saved in XML in certain structure = 2MB 2) I prepared a class which is aligned XML structure 3) then I read the XML data (at void Start) and based on that class I make for each case in XML one instance and put it into list 4) during the game I randomly pick up instances from the list. Issue: 35,000 instances => long build time + to start a game on handy takes 15min. I think it is because steps 1)-2)-3) are done each time when the game starts. How shall I approach this issue? Is XML good way? Is a Preprocessor a way to go? My approach seems to be completely wrong.

Comment: again the question: By `objects` you refer to `GameObject`s? or just arbitrary array elements? Instantiating 35000 `GameObject`s indeed sounds like not the correct approach. You would e.g. rather fill a pure data class array with the deserialized information and pick a random entry from there to spawn the according `GameObject`. I think it would help to see your code or at least a [Minima reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I updated the question + added example code. Please have a look if more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the main thing that makes it slow is all your "manual" parsing of the file.

As said I think it would be way faster using an [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer).

Also rather place your XML file in the [`Assets/StreamingAssets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) folder (-> create this folder if it doesn't exist). This prevents your XML content to be loaded into memory all the time.

And then you could use e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class ItemDefinition
{   
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int size;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public float weight;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public float digit1;
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("xml")]
public class XmlData
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<ItemDefinition> items;
}
```

The according XML content would then have to be slightly adjusted to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <item size="0" weight="0" digit1="0" />
  <item size="0" weight="0" digit1="0" />
  <item size="0" weight="0" digit1="0" />
</xml>
```

And then you could simply use e.g.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

...

public void Load()
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "example.xml");
    if(!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Couldn't find xml file at \"{filePath}\"!");
        return;
    }
    
    XmlData result = null;
    
    using(var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlData));
        result = (XmlData) serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }

    itemList = result.Items;
}
```

For not letting the User feal the lag I would also move this into an asynchronous `Task` and wait for the results.

Here a little [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fzbkkp) ;)

> ...
>
> Deserialzing from file ....
>
> Finished loading 35000 items after 43 milliseconds

---

Now if you want to do this on build time you have to make sure that your classes and fields are **serializable**

```
[SerializeField] private List<ItemDefinition> itemList = new List<ItemDefinition>();
```

as a nice side effect it will now also show up in the Inspector.

And then you could e.g. use an [`IPreprocessBuildWithReport`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport.OnPreprocessBuild.html) to trigger this on build time if needed, you could however also simply do it at any time in the editor.

Comment: Hi, this looks very promising. I will rework it over the weekend and let you know the outcome then. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, I got this error message.... "XmlException: There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to Unicode." Please - do you have any quick idea what it could be? Thanks.

Comment: I slightly changed the code...  instead of  "var stream = File.Open" I use code "string fileText = File.ReadAllText()" ... as described here "http://codesaying.com/parse-xml-in-unity3d/"  ... Then it works. FINAL OUTCOME = 408 milliseconds (as I use many more attributes than in example). But that is still great. I will still play with asynchronous tasks to run it in bacground. Thank you for great help.

Comment: Well the issue against stream is still: this way you load the entire text into memory this not that efficient. A stream has the advantage of minimal memory impact